# Floating an element whose child elements are also floated

Tags: css, styles, css-float

I have a `div` and a `ul` that I'm trying to float to create two columns.  The items within the `ul` are also floated so they will expand horizontally before wrapping vertically:

http://jsfiddle.net/3dhHe/7/

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {list-style-type: none;}
    li {float:left; width:275px; min-height: 50px; padding: 12px; border-radius: 4px; border: 2px outset #eee;}
    .float-right {width: 300px; float: right; margin-left: 25px;}
    .float-left {float: left;}
</style>

<div class="float-right">
    This content should float to the right
</div>
<ul class="float-left">
    <li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li><li>Item 6</li><li>Item 7</li><li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

If I remove the float from the list items, then everything works as expected, however, when the `li` elements have a float applied, the `ul` element seems to 'lose' it's float.

Is there a way to force the ul to float to the left of the div, while allowing the contents of the ul to float?
Note: I need the width of the ul to be dynamic, so I can't set an explicit width to it.

Thanks!!!

---

### Update

I'm trying to achieve something like this:
[image: Float 2 Columns]

The text on the right can have a static width, but the `ul` containing the boxes should not have an explicit width (so that if the width of the browser is increased, then the "Test 3" box will move to the first row).

The problem I'm having is that if I don't set a width on the `ul`, then the text content is moved above the `ul`:

[image]

Is there a way to position the `div` first, then restrict the `ul` to only use the remaining space?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Please make it more clear what you want to do.

Comment: Could you please separate your CSS from your HTML in your fiddle?

Comment: "I need the width of the ul to be dynamic, so I can't set an explicit width to it". You can't force the list to be one column unless you restrict the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Achieve your goal:

**1**. All `li` inside the `ul` must be floated horizontally on 1 line.

When this is achieved:

**2**. The `ul` must find enough space beside the `div` to float beside it.

You must give the `ul` a `max-width`, to force it not to expand and take space as much as it wants, make sure its enough so that all of its children `li` are floated beside one another.

If the `max-width` isn't enough, then the `li` will have no strength to say **NO!**, and they will simply take new lines below each other.

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/3EmdM/

**Why is this happening?**

When you are telling the `li` to `float:left;` it is as if you're telling them : **Try your best to float left, take every space you can so you can float left, cry and complain to your Mum (ul) and tell her that you MUST float left! All of us on the same line!**.

When the `ul` noticed that not all its children `li` have floated on the same line, it takes a new line below the `div` so it can achieve that.

Here's [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/vAgS8/), notice that when the 2 `li` have floated beside each other **(1)**, and when there's enough space for the whole `ul` to be beside the `div`**(2)**, it will float beside it.

Here's [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/C2uh6/) with 2 `divs`, same result, the second `div` will not float until all its children `div` have floated inside of it **(1)**, and enough space have been found beside the other `div`**(2)**.

**UPDATE**

What you need is to have both the `div` and the `ul` inside a **Parent Div**, this `div` will have a `position:relatve;` and `min-width`, giving it a minimum width will allow it to expand when you maximize the browser, and it will allow it to become smaller but only to a limit.

Then give the child `div` the static `width`, let's say, `250px`, and give the `ul` a `position:absolute;` with `right:250px` or a little bit more (consider it as a `margin-right`).

```
<div style="position:relative; min-width:600px;">
<ul style="position:absolute; right:250px; left:0px; ">
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
</ul>
<div style="float:right; width:250px;">
    This content should float to the right
    <br />
    This content should float to the right
    <br />
    This content should float to the right
    <br />
    This content should float to the right
</div>
</div>
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/FFrev/